# xp windows icons bottom left of screen are missing

Tags: windows-xp, quicklaunch

For some reason my icons at the bottom left of my screen are gone.  I use to have the Chrome, fox reader, desktop, etc icons but are now gone.  How to I get them back? What did I do to remove them?

Answer (score 3):

Right click on your taskbar, go to properties. Make sure "Show Quick Launch" is checked.

Another method is to right click on the taskbar, choose "Toolbars" and then checking "Quick Launch"